# Change default messages from Poll?

Tags: 7, polls

We're running the core Poll module on our site, and we'd like to change the default messages that it generates. I'm meaning stuff like `Your vote could not be recorded because you did not select any of the choices.`

I looked at the poll content type, but there weren't any settings for it there. It's apparently not listed under modules, because it's core, I suppose.

How can I change these messages from their defaults?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.  More options are described in the handbook page [Change default strings (text)](http://drupal.org/node/522036).

Answer (score -1):

Apparently these messages are hard-coded into the poll module, so to change them, one would need to hack core.

```
poll.module:738:    form_set_error( 'choice', t('Your vote could not be recorded because you did not select any of the choices.'));
```

Comment: No, this is incorrect.  See Dylan's answer.

Comment: "hacking core" is a big no-no in the Drupal world. I'm still pretty new myself but heard that message loud and clear ;-)  Poll module is just printing a general error message which can be intercepted in a hook_form_alter and replaced with your own error message.

Comment: One of the two methods that Dylan outlines really are the proper solution.  A hook_form_alter in this situation is serious overkill.